# WordPress: Get current post_meta after clicking "Update" button, Check value, then update_post_meta for another post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm customizing my WordPress admin panel and turning it to some kind of HRM system. Everything works fine. But I have a problem.

Currently, my panel has several custom post type. In some of these, there are status fields that created with ACF (Advanced Custom Fields). For example, users submit their request in these custom post types and I approve or disapprove the request through the drop-down list field.

Two of these custom post types are related to each other. Such that if the "status" of a request is approved or not approved in `leave requests` CPT, it is necessary to update a "field/post_meta" in another post from another custom post type called `Entry and exit list`.

---

**So in summary**; I need to make the system like this:

1. In **edit** page of a custom post type's (leave request) post in admin panel, I change a drop-down field (Approval or disapproval of the request)
2. Then I click on `Update/Publish` button (leave request CPT) to update the request's status field.
3. **The part I need**: Now after clicking of `Update/Publish` button, It should get current selected or current value of request's status field. Then based on value, It should conditionally update post_mata for another post.

---

**Currently / Problem**:

My code can do as I want but it also get previous field's value, instead of only current new selected value of field. It should only get new changed value, not what is submitted before.

---

**My code:**

This is my `function` in `functions.php` file of my theme:

```
function update_vosooli_status_to_portal( $post_id, $post ) {

    global $wpdb,$post;

    // ID of second post that we should update it
    // The ID is stored in current post meta (custom field).
    $target_post_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'parvande_id_invosolli', true);

    // Getting value of Status field. This is getting also previous value. This is problem:
    $request_status = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vosooli_status', true);
    
    // This is value when field is selected to approved
    // I'm using this to compare it with value of "$request_status"
    $request_status_approved = 'Approved Request';
    
    // Check if "$request_status" is equal to "$request_status_approved"
    if( $request_status == $request_status_approved ) {
        // This will update another post meta in another post with custom value
        update_post_meta($target_post_id, 'parvandeh_completaion', 'The staff took leave');
    }
}

// my CPT is "vosooli" so I used "publish_vosooli" to run functions when updating the post
add_action( 'publish_vosooli',  'update_vosooli_status_to_portal', 10, 2 );
```

This code currently doing what it coded for, But instead of only getting current new value, it get previous (value of field when post opened in edit mode and before input field changed).

---

**My thoughts on this:**

If we could let the new value of field update to database (save to post) when clicking publish button, then run this function, it will work fine. If we first save post with all fields, then run my function and get value and check the value, then there is no reason for problem. Am i right?

This part is I can't manage to fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code, this line:

```php
    // Getting value of Status field. This is getting also previous value. This is problem:
    $request_status = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vosooli_status', true);
```

depends on when your hook gets fire gets different results, (if the hook you are using fire before save of the post or after saving. it get the previous or the new status) ; but you have the current status in `$_POST`:

```php
    $request_status = $_POST['vosooli_status'];
    // you also may need to validate the input
    // $request_status = in_array($_POST['vosooli_status'],[0,1])??0;
```

or you can use `save_post_vosooli` hook which fires once the post has been saved.
wp docs for `save_post_[cpt]`:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/

full code:

```php
function update_vosooli_status_to_portal( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) and DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $_POST['change_to_your_input_name'] == 'Approved Request' ) {
        $target_post_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'parvande_id_invosolli', true );
        update_post_meta( $target_post_id, 'parvandeh_completaion', 'The staff took leave' );
    }

}

add_action( 'save_post_vosooli', 'update_vosooli_status_to_portal', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But the problem still here! I have to save post 2 times to functions run. It should run for first time i update post and run function

Comment: @TLPMasih , i updated my answer and added the full code, i had the similar task in one of my project and that worked, i hope it helps you.